# Importando css no React JS

Tags: html, css, react

Bom dia, sou novo no React e estou tentando importar um arquivo css no meu componente Cabecalho, porem eu nao estou conseguindo fazer isso com o import normal, eu gostaria de saber como fazer isso pois ele nao esta achando o meu arquivo css, Obrigado desde já

meu arquivo css: aplication\css\style.css

esse é o erro que ele estando dando no browser
[image: erro do browser]

tirei um print do meu projeto também

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual a pasta do Cabecalho.js? Perceba que você está tentando pegar dentro dessa pasta o arquivo style.css

Comment: entao o Cabecalho.js esta nesse diretorio : aplication\src\components\Cabecalho.js , porem eu ja havia tentado passar esse caminho e parece que ele nao esta reconhecendo os arquivos css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que, no seu código, você está dizendo que o arquivo `style.css` está no caminho `aplication\src\components\`, já que você está importando da seguinte forma:

```
import './style.css'; //Aqui diz para procurar um style.css na pasta atual
```

Outro problema é que o webpack está configurado para enxergar a pasta src como raíz, por isso é necessário colocar a pasta css dentro da pasta src e substituir a importação por:

```
import '../css/style.css'; //Aqui sobe um nível (src), entra na pasta css e busca por style.css
```

Comment: eu acabei de tentar mas tbm n deu certo, ele exibiu o seguinte erro : 

./src/components/Cabecalho.js
Module not found: You attempted to import ../../css/style.css which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.

Comment: O problema é que ele só enxerga dentro da pasta `src`, então tem que colocar a pasta css pra dentro da pasta src. Editei minha resposta com isso.

Comment: deu certo, muito obrigado pela ajuda !!!

Comment: @GiovanniManganotti caso você possa, selecione como resposta, por favor (: